# проблема с выводом подстрочного текста

Tags: java, android, xml

в файле `strings.xml` в данных для массива занесено так `<item>Mg₃Si₄O₁₀(OH)₂</item>` при работе приложения выводится все верно, кроме `₀` выглядит так, как на скрине [image].

Как этот 0 сделать видимым?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Si <sub><small>4</small></sub>O<sub><small>10</small></sub>"));
```

Или использовать Spannable - SuperscriptSpan http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/style/SuperscriptSpan.html